# How to set up Dynamic UI Routing for a simple Fulcro app

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, fulcro

I've crawled through some of the [web](http://book.fulcrologic.com/#_dynamic_router) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQpmKWBm9HE&10m50s=) documentation for routing. But I'm failing to get Dynamic UI Routing working for a simple set of pages.

> root.cljs

```
(ns ui.root)
;; ...

(defsc Index [this props]
  {:query [:index]
   :ident (fn [] [:id :index])
   :route-segment ["index"]
   :initial-state {}}

  (h3 "Index"))

(defsc Landing [this props]
  {:query [:landing]
   :ident (fn [] [:id :landing])
   :route-segment ["landing"]
   :initial-state {}}

  (h3 "Landing"))

(defsc Settings [this props]
  {:query [:settings]
   :ident (fn [] [:id :settings])
   :route-segment ["settings"]
   :initial-state {}}

  (h3 "Setting"))


(dr/defrouter TopRouter [this {:keys [current-state] :as props}]
  {:router-targets [Game Settings Landing Index]
   :initial-state (fn [{:keys [current-state]}]
                    {:current-state current-state})}

  (case current-state
    :pending (dom/div "Loading...")
    :failed (dom/div "Failed!")
    (dom/div "No route selected.")))

(def ui-top-router (comp/factory TopRouter))


(defsc Root [this {:keys [router] :as props}]
  {:query [{:router (comp/get-query TopRouter)}]
   :ident (fn [] [:id :root])

   :initial-state (fn [_]
                    {:top-router (comp/get-initial-state TopRouter {:current-state :pending})
                     :index {:id 1}
                     :landing {:id 1}
                     :settings {:id 1}})

   :componentDidMount (fn [_] (log/info "Root Initial State /" (prim/get-initial-state Root {})))}

  (log/info "Root Props /" this props)
  (ui-top-router router {:current-state :pending}))
```

> client.cljs

```
(ns client)
...

(app/mount! @app root/Root "app" {:initialize-state? true
                                  :foo :bar})
```

Q: Initial load gives this output. How do we pass props into the Root component? I expect to see at least `{:foo :bar}`.

```
INFO [ui.root:81] - Root Props / [object Object] {}
INFO [ui.root:53] - TopRouter Props / {:current-state nil, :route-factory #object[cljs.core.MetaFn], :pending-path-segment nil, :route-props nil}
INFO [ui.root:77] - Root Initial State / nil
```

Q: If this is my initial state, is the `:query` and `:ident` right? And do they (:query + :ident) correspond to the `:route-segment` ? Do they need to?

```
{:index {:id 1}
 :landing {:id 1}
 :settings {:id 1}}
```

Q: How do we kick off the initial route? Calling this fails with the below message.

```
(dr/change-route app ["index"])

INFO [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.rendering.ident-optimized-render:146] - Optimized render failed. Falling back to root render.
```

**>> UPDATE <<**

I was able to get a working Fulcro Root `:initial-state`, and `:query` and `:ident` on child components.

On initial load, the router fails with this.

```
INFO [beatthemarket.ui.root:61] - TopRouter Props / {:current-state nil, :route-factory #object[cljs.core.MetaFn], :pending-path-segment nil, :route-props {:index/id 1, :index/text "Index Text"}}

core.cljs:159 ERROR [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.routing.dynamic-routing:410] - will-enter for router target beatthemarket.ui.root/Index did not return a valid ident. Instead it returned:  [:index/id nil]
core.cljs:159 ERROR [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.routing.dynamic-routing:410] - will-enter for router target beatthemarket.ui.root/Index did not return a valid ident. Instead it returned:  [:index/id nil]

browser.cljs:25 shadow-cljs: WebSocket connected!
browser.cljs:25 shadow-cljs: REPL session start successful

core.cljs:159 INFO [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.algorithms.indexing:104] - component beatthemarket.ui.root/Index's ident ([:index/id nil]) has a `nil` second element. This warning can be safely ignored if that is intended.
```

So a command like `(dr/change-route app (dr/path-to root/Index))` fails with this.

```
react_devtools_backend.js:6 ERROR [com.fulcrologic.fulcro.routing.dynamic-routing:410] - will-enter for router target beatthemarket.ui.root/Index did not return a valid ident. Instead it returned:  [:index/id nil]
```

These are my [client.cljs](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket.fulcro/blob/3a646f29b46b3b100e8835c2b00011f312c421e6/src/main/beatthemarket/client.cljs) and [root.cljs](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket.fulcro/blob/3a646f29b46b3b100e8835c2b00011f312c421e6/src/main/beatthemarket/ui/root.cljs) look like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Root initial state should be calling `(comp/get-initial-state Index)`. You have an initial state set on Index but it's different than the initial state that Root gives.

Also, a big part of Fulcro (and React) is that you build a tree of components and a tree of data and they need to match.

The way you have it here, there's no connection between "Root" and "Index" because Root only renders `(ui-top-router router)`. You're getting the data for Index by having a query for `{:root/index (comp/get-query Index)}` but you're not creating the connection between Root and Index by having Root call Index and pass in that data. You need a `(ui-index index)` inside Root.

And if you do that, then in that `(ui-index index)` call, `index` will take the value that you're setting with `:initial-state`. That's why you'll also need to update initial-state to call `comp/get-initial-state` so that you can get the `:index/id 1` value that you're setting in the Index component's initial state.

```
(defsc Index [this {:index/keys [id text]}]
  {:query [:index/id :index/text]
   :ident [:index/id :index/id]
   :route-segment ["index"]
   :initial-state {:index/id 1
                   :index/text :param/text}}

  (h3 text))

(defsc Root [this {:root/keys [router index landing game settings]}]
  {:query [{:root/router (comp/get-query TopRouter)}
           {:root/index (comp/get-query Index)}
           {:root/landing (comp/get-query Landing)}
           {:root/game (comp/get-query Game)}
           {:root/settings (comp/get-query Settings)}]

   :initial-state {:root/router {}
                   :root/index {:text "Index Text"}
                   :root/landing {:text "Landing Text"}
                   :root/game {:text "Game Text"}
                   :root/settings {:text "Settings Text"}}}
  (when router
   (dom/div (ui-top-router router))))
```

After all of that is addressed, here's the next thing you might be interested in.

You probably won't always want to hard-code `index/id 1`. You might need to fetch data from a server in order to have anything to render.

That's where `:will-enter` and "deferred routing" come into play. See the example below and the docs at http://book.fulcrologic.com/#_router_rendering_of_a_deferred_ui.

```
(defsc Person [this {:ui/keys      [modified?]
                     :person/keys  [id name]
                     :address/keys [city state]
                     :as           props}]
  {:query               [:ui/modified? :person/id :person/name :address/city :address/state]
   :ident               :person/id
   :route-segment       ["person" :person/id]
   :route-cancelled     (fn [{:person/keys [id]}]
                          (log/info "Routing cancelled to user " id))
   :allow-route-change? (fn [this {:ui/keys [modified?]}]
                          (when modified?
                            #?(:cljs (js/alert "You cannot navigate until the user is not modified!")))
                          (not modified?))
   :will-enter          (fn [app {:person/keys [id] :as route-params}]
                          (log/info "Will enter user with route params " route-params)
                          ;; be sure to convert strings to int for this case
                          (let [id (if (string? id) (edn/read-string id) id)]
                            (dr/route-deferred [:person/id id]
                                               #(df/load app [:person/id id] Person
                                                         {:post-mutation        `dr/target-ready
                                                          :post-mutation-params {:target [:person/id id]}}))))}
```

Comment: You say 'You need a `(ui-index index)` inside Root.' but you don't have that in your `defsc Root`. I think there needs to be a connection from `Root` to `Index` via query, but not via rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you first have to fix the Ident problem with your Index component.

Does routing work for the other components?